# How to set the ScrollView to fit in react native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, flexbox

How to set the ScrollView to "take all the remaining space" instead of setting height: XXXX ?

```
 <ScrollView >
         <View style={{
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'column',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
      }}>
        <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'powderblue'}} />
        <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'skyblue'}} />
        <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'steelblue'}} />
        </View>
           </ScrollView>
```

Comment: check this: https://github.com/GeekyAnts/react-native-easy-grid

Comment: @JigarShah i do not want to use any external library

Comment: With `ScrollView` it may not be possible. You need give `height` to all element in order to cover full `height`. You can assign that `height` dynamically using screen height. That would work for all screen.

Answer (score 3):

```
 <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{flex:1}}>
      ...
 </ScrollView>
```

use contentContainerStyle for fitting the scroolView to the screen